# What's the correct verb to use to describe the phenomenon of going from calling someone 'vous' to calling someone 'tu'?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot

The kind of verb that can only exist in language such as French with different ways of referring to people in the second person, what is the verb (or verbs) that describe the phenomenon of switching to a 'more intimate' mode of address?  I'm sure I've seen a phrase in the past that basically meant "let's start calling each other 'tu'", but there was a single verb for the second part of the sentence, such that if the verb was *xxx*, the sentence would read "let's xxx".  What could that verb have been?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Le verbe est "[tutoyer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/tutoyer)", par opposition à "[vouvoyer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/vouvoyer)". Note qu'il décrit le fait de dire "tu", mais par extension, aussi le passage de la forme "tu" à la forme "vous".
En général, la question posée est ["On se tutoie?"](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie)

You're looking for the verb *"[tutoyer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/morphologie/tutoyer)"*, which denotes the way of saying *"tu"* to each other and, by extension, to transition from using *"vous"* to using *"tu"*.

Comment: "Vousoyer" et "voussoyer" s'utilisent aussi comme synonyme de "vouvoyer".

Answer (score 7):

En Suisse romande on peut dire ["faire schmolitz"](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/faire-schmolitz/)

> Cérémonie consistant à croiser les verres, faire cul sec et se tutoyer ensuite.
>   Proposer le tutoiement.

D'après [Wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schmolitz):

> Cette expression est empruntée à l'argot estudiantin allemand du 18e siècle. Malgré sa consonance germanique, cette expression est semble-t-il inconnue en Suisse alémanique où elle est remplacée par *Duzis mache*.

Comment: Un _rituel_ pour ça? Excellent!

Answer (score 4):

En français "standard" (puisque visiblement certaines régions ont une expression), je ne connais pas d'expression permettant d'exprimer le passage du vouvoiement au tutoiement.

Cependant, on pourrait utiliser le verbe "se mettre à":

> Il s'est mis à me tutoyer.

Comment: Ou "Il ne me vouvoie plus" (A ne pas confondre avec "Il ne vous voit plus")

Answer (score 3):

Effectivement les mots utilisés sont "tutoyer" et "vouvoyer" mais cela n'indique qu'un état, pas la transition.

Ainsi on peut effectivement dire

> On peut se tutoyer
>   Tu n'es pas obligé de me tutoyer

Plus généralement, le passage de l'un à l'autre implique un passage d'un mode formel, à un mode informel.

On peut ainsi dire "se passer des formalités" :

> Entre nous, on peut se passer des formalités.
>   Oublions les formalités, tu peux me tutoyer.

Comment: D'accord sur le fait que le verbe n'indique théoriquement qu'un état, mais je reste convaincu qu'il peut aussi sous-entendre la transition.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec @Joubarc pour le fait qu'on utilise de façon implicite le verbe tutoyer pour décrire la transition également, même si ce n'est pas "exact" au sens grammatical.

Answer (score 2):

Pourquoi pas « passer au tutoiement » ?